# Centos 5.5 SoftRaid Grub Installation

Tags: centos, raid, installation, software-raid, grub

I did the Soft RAID 1 installation with Centos 5.5 on my server with 2 SATA 1TB disks.

I followed this great guide here:
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SoftwareRAIDonCentOS5

However, there is one bit difference, that my Grub is default installing to /dev/md0, not /dev/sda as mentioned in that guide. Just wondering if my Grub is installed in /dev/md0, do I still need to do the section 2 of the guide?

Thanks,
tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install grub to the MBRs of `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, along with the grub files going to `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`, for grub to boot properly.